# Stripe | OAuth is disabled for this account

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working with Stripe Dashboard.

I am getting this error - `OAuth is disabled for this account.`

When i click on "Test the OAuth flow" then i am getting above error.

Can anyone please help me like how can i enable the oAuth?

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an account-specific issue. You need to log into your account and reach out to Stripe's support using the form at https://support.stripe.com/email to receive help about this.